# Question on Textmate Ruby on Rails bundle, what's the difference on HTML(Rails) mode and Ruby on Rails mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, textmatebundles

When developing Rails project using `Textmate`, there are some related modes. When pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, you will get a list of modes:

- Ruby
- HTML (Rails)
- Ruby on Rails (RJS)
- Ruby on Rails
- SQL (Rails)

I want to know the difference between `HTML (Rails)` and `Ruby on Rails`. Anyone can explain it please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby on Rails mode is for working with controllers/models/helpers etc

HTML (Rails) mode is for dealing with views